# java newrelic agent throwing classnotfound exception

Tags: java, newrelic

I am trying to install newrelic on a linux machine with tomcat 7. This installation does not have a catalina.sh so cannot use the newrelic installer.

I tried the manula approach of adding the newrelic.jar to the javaagent like:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:/usr/share/tomcat7/newrelic/newrelic.jar"
```

But whenever I start the tomcat I get the following classnotfoundexception:

```
Unable to start New Relic agent: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
        at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(TransformerFactory.java:106)
        at com.newrelic.agent.extension.dom.ExtensionDomParser.getTransformerFactory(ExtensionDomParser.java:360)
        at com.newrelic.agent.extension.dom.ExtensionDomParser.fixNamespace(ExtensionDomParser.java:337)
        at com.newrelic.agent.extension.dom.ExtensionDomParser.parseDocument(ExtensionDomParser.java:167)
        at com.newrelic.agent.extension.dom.ExtensionDomParser.readFile(ExtensionDomParser.java:152)
        at com.newrelic.agent.extension.ExtensionParsers$3.parse(ExtensionParsers.java:46)
        at com.newrelic.agent.extension.JarExtension.<init>(JarExtension.java:59)
        at com.newrelic.agent.extension.JarExtension.<init>(JarExtension.java:104)
        at com.newrelic.agent.extension.ExtensionService.initializeBuiltInExtensions(ExtensionService.java:388)
        at com.newrelic.agent.extension.ExtensionService.doStart(ExtensionService.java:145)
        at com.newrelic.agent.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:54)
        at com.newrelic.agent.service.ServiceManagerImpl.doStart(ServiceManagerImpl.java:124)
        at com.newrelic.agent.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:54)
        at com.newrelic.agent.Agent.premain(Agent.java:208)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
        at com.newrelic.bootstrap.BootstrapAgent.premain(BootstrapAgent.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:343)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:358)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/apache/xalan/processor/TransformerFactoryImpl
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(FactoryFinder.java:124)
        at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:179)
```

I have tried everything I could for this, but nothing works. I have even added the xalan jar manually to the tomcat lib but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have xalan.jar installed.  If it is installed, it may be in the wrong place.  You probably need it at the container level, here is a blog post that discusses this issue (tomcat5 but most of the advice should still apply).

http://doookstechstuff.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-fix-tomcat5-on-rhel5.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the location where you put the xalan.jar is in the classpath and that the user account you're running tomcat under has access to it.  If you have dropped it in the tomcat /lib folder make sure the perms for the .jar file match the other objects in the folder.

Let us know if this helps.  If you need additional information it might be best to create a ticket with New Relic Support (http://support.newrelic.com).